# Twitter share button doesn't validate WC3

Tags: validation, twitter, share

I thought there would be an answer for this question, I need a little help getting around the validation problems with the Twitter share button. 
The code provided by twitter looks like this and I've placed it directly into the div where I want it to appear:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="vertical"       data-via="smith_and_sons">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

The weird link parameters don't validate, can I pass this button to a div via javascript and use cdata to skip validation in the head? How would I go about doing this? Help would be really appreciated, thanks a lot.

Sofi

Comment: I recommend you to read http://www.symetris.ca/blog/validating-social-networking-buttons

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem (Facebook,Twitter,Google plus one Share Buttons validation errors).
for twitter i used

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?count=vertical&amp;"
class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a> script type="text/javascript"
src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

now is valid